# How do I make a Discord bot send a message locally

Tags: python, discord, bots

I want it to look like this:

[image: this].

I'm coding this Discord bot in Python. Can you tell the code to make it privately message you like this?

I'm expecting Python code that will send a message to you locally. When I asked ChatGPT, it came up with code to DM the user, I don't want that.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't write it for you. Please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?
If you don't know how to start, tutorials and text books would be a better choice. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

For example when you are using discord.py you can react to interaction "empheral" this way:

```
async def test(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Test", ephemeral=True)
```